# Check for existence of files prior to acting on them

Tags: bash, find, directory, bash-script

In one of my processes I check for existence of files older than 31 days, and then do stuff with them.

```
find /my/directory/*txt -mtime +31 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

All this is well and fine if files are in `/my/directory/`, but when there are no files present I get an error:

```
find: `/my/directory/*txt': No such file or directory
```

If I issue:

```
touch /my/directory/a_new_file.txt
```

and run the same command again

```
find /my/directory/*txt -mtime +31 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

There are no errors.

Is there a way to verify that files exist in a directory before attempting any work on them?

Comment: Why not `find /my/directory/ -mtime +31 -exec ls -ld {} +`? Do you really intend to ommit dot files in `/my/directory` only (by having the shell expand the `*` there)?

Comment: Be careful: there's an entire class of bugs that can happen if you have time interval between check and use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use  These bugs can be particularly hard to ferret out, as the code certainly looks correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how `find` works. The first argument is a directory to search through (or a single file name). If you want to give patterns, you should use `-name` or `-iname` or `-regex` or similar options. For example:

```
find /my/directory/ -name "*txt" -mtime +31 -ls
```

I also changed `-exec ls {} \;` to use the `-ls` option of find which does the same thing more efficiently.

The only way of checking would be to run an `ls` or another `find` first and that seems silly in order to avoid a completely harmless error message.

If you want, you can also specify that you are looking for normal file, no directories etc by using `-type`:

```
find /my/directory/ -type f -name "*txt" -mtime +31 -ls
```

This will find all `.txt` files including those in subdirectories of `/my/directory`, if that is not what you want, specify a maximum depth:

```
find /my/directory/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*txt" -mtime +31 -ls
```

Comment: I left an important detail from my question.  It's been updated.  My find command actually looks like this:  `find /my/directory/*txt -mtime +31 -exec ls -l {} \;`

Comment: @terdon `-ls` does not expand directories under `/my/directory` as does `-exec ls -l {};` (although might be what questioner wants)

Comment: @Zelda it doesn't? It does on my system, are you using GNU find?

Comment: `ls` is not what's in my script.  Just used it as an example.   I just found a better way of handling the problem:  `find /my/directory/ -type f \( -name "*.txt" \) -print`

Comment: @terdon if you can update your answer to fit my question I'll re-accept your answer.  Right now the answer doesn't fit on account of my omission of an important detail. (Sorry).

Comment: @acoder you don't need the parentheses, or the print either, just `find /my/directory/ -type f -name "*txt"`

Comment: @terdon, the question is already updated.

Comment: This also matches `*txt` files in subdirectories, which isn't the case in the question. Adding `-maxdepth 1` would change that.

Comment: @Gilles I had assumed that was what the OP was after with `/my/directory/*`. Might as well mention it though, answer edited.